# Renaming a file in a git repo with keeping the author of the file?

Tags: git, github

- I have changed the name of a file in the repo.
- The author of the file was `User1`.
- Now I am the author of the entire file (commit).
- How to avoid changing the real author of the file, and rename the file?

## Edit

When I blame a file in Github, it shows that all the contents (`SLOC`, `lines of code`) in the file are authored by `me` but in reality, I just changed the name of the file.

Comment: Did you **only** rename the file?

Comment: Yes!
I just changed its name from `new-file.html` to `welcome.html`, that's it.

Comment: Then no, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

*Files* do not have authors, in Git.  *Commits* have authors.

Commits do hold files—but every commit holds *every* file.  So if you made commit `a123456`, you're the author of *every* file in that commit, if you want to pretend that files have authors.  It does not matter whether the file is changed or not.

Some—well, practically all—*Git repository viewers* have option to tell you: *between commit `a123456` and commit `b789abc`, these files changed*. They do this by extracting (to a temporary area, in memory really) the two commits—each of which has its own separate author—and then seeing if the files in those commits are entirely the same, or if any given file has some change in it.

If the viewer says *between adjacent commits `a123456` (parent) and `b789abc` (child), file `new-file.html` changed names to `welcome.html`, but no lines have changed*, then *you* should think of this as:

- Aha: the author of commit `b789abc` renamed the file, but I should keep looking further back to see who actually *wrote* the file.
- If you look back further, you may find that the file existed in a bunch of commits unchanged for a while before `a123456`, but back in commit-pair `<parent=6abc043, child=badf00d>` some *lines* in the file changed.  That suggests that the author of commit `badf00d` is the author of those *lines* in the file.  The remaining lines require looking further back.

There is a Git command-line command that does this for you, called `git blame`.  It starts with a commit you name—the default is your current commit, known as `HEAD`—and works backwards, as Git always does, commit by commit.  It looks to see who changed what part(s) of the file, and tells you when something interesting happened.  Most commits mostly don't *change* most files, which makes them uninteresting; `git blame` omits mentioning them, since *in commit `cafedad`, nothing happened to your file* is not useful information.

Comment: I know, but there is a problem, the `git blame` should show me that `You` changed the file name but instead it shows that `You` changed everything inside the file. and It raises up my marks in Github insights.

Comment: You might consider suggesting that GitHub should check for file renames and count them differently. Your particular suggestion to GitHub alone is unlikely to make a difference, but if *many* people make similar suggestions, the GitHub folks will see that this is a desirable feature.